# Is battery plugged or not in real time(on Linux), need quick fix in code

Tags: python, battery

I have a weird code which is intended to perform as follow: When the code is running it should check if the battery is plugged or not. if that's the case then use the alarm sound. (using Linux)

**The problem:** in while loop variable plugged value never changes.
It does not matter if the battery is plugged or not. When I am charging the laptop and start the program the alarm goes on **but if I unplugged it nothing changes.**

I have tried time.sleep() method thought program needed some time to update the current plugged value but nothing promising so far...

```py
import psutil
import os
import time

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
plugged = battery.power_plugged

while plugged:
    os.system('aplay klax_11.wav')
    time.sleep(5)
    plugged = battery.power_plugged
```

Desirable behaviour is next: While loop should break when I unplugged the device from a power source.

Answer (score 0):

battery instance need to be updated as well.

```py
while plugged:
    os.system('aplay klax_11.wav')
    time.sleep(5)
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    plugged = battery.power_plugged
```